# Facebook Messenger ID Matching API works only for Administrators

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger, facebook-chatbot

I have a messenger app and I want to check if the messenger user is also a registered user of my website. I'm using Facebook's [id matching api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts) feature to get the real facebook id using the psid returned by messenger. However, it only works only for me, who is the administrator of the app. When I use other user's psid to do the request I get an empty data though they are registered on my website via Facebook.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you got the necessary permissions from Facebook? In the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts), it is said that _"Your initial call to the API may trigger an app review that can take approximately 48 hours to complete."_.

Answer (score 0):

You have to publish your bot before you can use ID Matching API. Facebook require that you have a valid approved bot in order to use this API.